# Call python function in xml for set attribute of form view in odoo 13

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13, formview

I have a form view and I want to set the create and edit attributes to it dynamically.
here is my form view record:

```
 <record model="ir.ui.view" id="estate_property_type_form">
            <field name="name">estate_property_type_form</field>
            <field name="model">estate.property.type</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form>
                    <sheet>
                           some fileds...
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

and I used xpath tag to set create and edit attributes there but I can't call my function in estate.property.type model here is my record for set attributes  :
'''

```
<record id="changing_attrs" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">changing attrs</field>
            <field name="model">estate.property.type</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="estate_property_type_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//form" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="create">model_estate_property_type_form.test()</attribute>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

where in test function I do some logic and return true or false.
I also tried user.env['estate.property.type'].test(), estate.property.type.test() and test() between attribute tags but it didn't work. can someone help me to call my function here or tell me another way to set form attributes dynamically?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fields_view_get` method. replace `YourClass` and `your_text()` properly,

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(YourClass, self).fields_view_get(
        view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu
    )
    doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
    if view_type == 'form' and self.your_test():
        for node in doc.xpath('//{}'.format(view_type)):
            node.set('create', '0')
    res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc, encoding='unicode')
    return res
```

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.

Comment: thanks for your attention, it worked :)

Comment: You can mark this answer as acepted to help others.